# Confused about media queries and resolution?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am a beginner and have been working on my first responsive site with media queries.

A site I was reading told me some standard ones were

768-1024 for tablets

320-480 for smart phones.

I used these to begin, However, when I open it with my note 3 I get the tablet version and the menu is too small for it.  This same result happens with an iphone 4.

Even when I changed the smart phone range to 320-767, both phones still are using the "tablet" layout.   The note 3 has a width of 720 correct?  so with this it should force it into the smart phone query right?  Am I misunderstanding this?  How can it tell the difference between something small but with a high resolution like the note 3 to a tablet so that I can have larger elements on the note3?

If someone could explain to me what is going wrong here I would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The note 3 has a 1920x1080 resolution, not a width of 720 pixels.

Instead of selecting pre-defined values for targetting specific devices, it is recommended to use values suited to your content specifically. That way, all devices can expect an appropriate layout, usually with more simple media-query rules too. There are just too many devices out there today to pick specific values.

Comment: ah ok I see.  Something I still don't understand though is how do you make something look proper on something like a note3 when it has the same resolution as my computer monitor but the actual note3 screen is so much smaller?  Like is there a way to tell the difference from a mobile defice running at 1920x1080 and a large computer monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah @rwzy 1920x1080 I should say. He must design first in mobile then going larger on desktop and tablet, He must choose [Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive#set-your-first-breakpoint) based on the content not on defines screen sizes.

Comment: Ok thank you for the response I see I was looking at this the wrong way.  Altho I am still confused at how you can treat a device like a note 3 like a mobile because of its small screen size despite its large 1920x1080 resolution.  Can it even tell the difference if its a mobile device or a computer monitor running at 1920x1080?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your website based on the screen sizes only well use media queries also if you based it on resolutions also media queries best suite your problems. try http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-retina-display/